# Merging two log files with filebeat/logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am trying to merge two different logs from different server locations where logstash is running but not finding any solution for this. Is there any way to merge two different logs based on the timestamp with the help of filebeat and logstash?

Comment: You need to provide more info, some sample log data than you want to merge and how you want to merge

Comment: Hi Val, my scenario is I am fetching two log files from different server locations and I want to merge those two log file contents into one file before handing over to elastisearch. This is a normal log with timestamp and INFO and DEBUG information.

Comment: Ok, but on which criteria do you want to merge your data?

Comment: Hi Val, I dont need to merge it on a timestamp basis. It is okay if i merge the files simply one after another.

Comment: Provide an example please

Comment: Suppose, I am running two filebeat instances in two nodes i.e. Node-1 and Node-2 and the nodes have their own logs. These filebeat instances should save the output file in Node-3 which will be a merged output of both the Node-1 and Node-2 instances. Suppose Node-1 log